# How do I fix my activity arrangements in my application?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I have these activities which are the `WelcomePage`, `Main`, `GameView` and `Finish`.
The `WelcomePage` class is where my play button is Located. When the play button is press, it calls the `Main` class which shows the `GameView` class(`GameView` class is my `SurfaceView`).

In the `Main` class, I have this code:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,WelcomePage.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

so that when the user hits the Home and the power button, The `WelcomePage` pops up in the screen again.

While in the `GameView` Class, I have this code:

```
Context context = getContext(); 
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Finish.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

So that on a certain action of the user, the game would be finish and the `Finish` Class would pop up.

The problem is the `Finish` Class only pops up in the screen for about 3 seconds and then the `WelcomePage` Class shows up again. How do I fix this problem.